# How to check preconditions before login wordpress

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

Greetings

I want to check user status before login. e.g if user role is tester  don't login. else login.

Thanks

Comment: are you using a plugin??

Answer (score 0):

```
add_action( 'get_header', 'no_testers' );
function no_testers() {
    if ( current_user_can( 'tester_only_capability' ))
        $logout_url = wp_login_url().'?mode=maintainance';
        wp_logout();
        wp_redirect( $logout_url, 302 );
}
```

Replace `tester_only_capability` with something only the tester can do.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `wp_authenticate` to use a custom login mechanism before you involve WordPress.

```
<?php
  add_action( 'wp_authenticate' , 'check_custom_authentication' );
  function check_custom_authentication ( $username ) {
    // Get user role by username & put your logic
  }
?>
```